# Flutter - Build App bundle error - Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to build app bundle but i am getting the following error:

> Failed to read key upload from store "/Users/giorgosbillis/development/2023/altertrip app/altertrip_app/android/app/upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

I have placed the key.properties file in the android root folder and the upload-keystore.jks in the android/app directory.

The key.properties are:

```
storePassword=s>+Ke<5N"=/2h'KJ
keyPassword=s>+Ke<5N"=/2h'KJ
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=../app/upload-keystore.jks
```

Any help would be much appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Working solution ❇️

To fix this error, follow these pretty simple steps.

##### Regenerate a new keystore

Run the command to generate a keystore as explained in the official documentation.

- If you're on Linux or Mac, you run `keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload  -storetype JKS`
- If you're on windows, you run `keytool -genkey -v -keystore %userprofile%\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload`

#### Make sure you added -storetype

Make sure you did not forget to add `-storetype JKS` extra param. In fact, adding this extra parameter will fix the problem

#### Happy coding

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Unfortunately it does not let me generate a new file. Even if I delete the old file I get this message: keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Key pair not generated, alias <upload> already exists
java.lang.Exception: Key pair not generated, alias <upload> already exists
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doGenKeyPair(Main.java:1958)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1181)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:420)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main

Comment: Just delete the old one and retry generation. Or you change the alias attribute, from upload to `your_new_alias`